# If Condition inside SOQL Salesforce

Tags: apex, soql, query

In my class i have a SOQL query;

```
List<Lead> matchingLeadsList = [
    SELECT Id, Status FROM Lead WHERE IsConverted = false AND (
        Email=:application_email OR MobilePhone =:application_mobile OR
        Email=:spjat_email or MobilePhone =:spjat_mobile
    )
];
```

The problem is, for some `Lead` records the `Email`/`MobilePhone` fields are null. If the method containing this query sends a null value for any of the referenced variables, then Null will be matched with null and query result will be wrong.

So I wanted to write if inside a query to avoid this situation. Any suggestions? It seems like its not possible to write if inside a query, Is there any workaround?

Comment: Use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to check if your parameters are NULL and if they are null don't include them in your SOQL.

Comment: Why not just do `(Email != null AND Email = :application_email) OR (Mobile != null AND Mobile = :application_mobile)` etc..?

Comment: Yeah...Silly me..I was thinking the wrong way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply get records where field **are not** null, and then check to see if they match the values in your variables.

For example, as we're looking at the following part of your SOQL:

```
(Email=:application_email or MobilePhone =:application_mobile or  Email=:spjat_email or MobilePhone =:spjat_mobile)
```

Just add "null checkers", so:

```
((Email != null AND (Email = :application_email OR Email = :spjat_email)) OR (MobilePhone != null AND (MobilePhone =:application_mobile OR MobilePhone =:spjat_mobile)))
```

This will check first if the value is null, if it's not null, check whether or not Email is equal to `application_email` or `spjat_email`, then do the same for the `MobilePhone` field.

Comment: By definition the email would not be null if it equals one of the merge properties. The issue here is that if the phone is valid and the email is null this query will still return a null value for email.

Comment: @Eric Maybe I've interpreted the question wrong, I assumed he meant that if someone left out, say `application_email ` (ergo, it's null) it would match with all records that don't have `Email` set?

Comment: could be. I read it differently and I could be wrong as well and that looks to be the case

Answer (score 2):

You can actually improve query performance *and* remove nulls from your filter at the same time. Don't use an `OR` clause where you can avoid it. Their performance is dreadful. Instead, use `IN` clauses here:

```
Set<String> emails = new Set<String> { application_email, spjat_email }
Set<String> phones = new Set<String> { application_mobile, spjat_mobile }

emails.remove(null);
phones.remove(null);

List<Lead> records = (emails.isEmpty() || phones.isEmpty()) ? new List<Lead>() :
    [SELECT Status FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :emails OR Phone IN :phones];
```

You can't remove the `OR` clauses entirely, but one is certainly better than three. Also, using a `Set` allows you to conveniently remove `null` from your filter. If all of your parameters were `null`, this approach simply returns an empty list without running a query.